# Arch Linux netinstall - conflicting packages on install

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, system-installation

I'm using the latest Arch Netinstall image. I just went through and selected about 150 packages to download and install. However, when I get to the "Install Packges" step, I get an error saying that I have two conflicting packages (openjdk6 and jre7-openjdk) and the install fails and sends me back to the menu.

The problem is, I don't know how to remove the conflicting package from my install list. If I go back to the list of packages, it erases the selections I made previously and I have to reselect each package all over again (I've done it twice already, no fun).

Is there a way to omit a package without having to reselect all of them?

Comment: Not sure about omitting packages but the reason they conflict is that they both provide the java-runtime.  If you need to install both jdk6 and jdk7 get the jdk6-compat package from the AUR.  It's probably a good idea to just do the minimum install and then use pacman to install packages after you have a booting system.  Welcome to Arch :)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMyers, and yeah I know why they're conflicting. I was just too quick and checked them both off when selecting packages ... I'm way to tired to be experimenting with new OS's :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can --ignore packages. This works:

```
pacman -S your list of packages --ignore openjdk6,jre7-openjdk
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I'll try this next time I'm installing Arch